# HornetQ commit ClientSession after onMessage

Tags: java, hornetq

Do I need to commit ClientSession after dealing with incoming message?

```
 ClientSession session = ... ;       
 clientConsumer.setMessageHandler(new MessageHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onMessage(ClientMessage message) {
   ...
   try {
     session.commit();
   } catch (HornetQException e) { }
   finally {
     session.close();
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your ClientSession to get in the constructor (createSession
) the parameter autoCommitSends and autoCommitAcks to be received by the user ofyour application.

this way you neutralize your question by letting your user decide on the commits